# VisualSVN and Slack

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, slack-api

I'm reviewing the slack-visualsvn integration guide and having some trouble here.

[Slack SVN Integration](http://slack.com/apps/A0F827LTA-subversion)

When you review the [example](https://github.com/tinyspeck/services-examples/blob/master/subversion.pl) it doesn't give details as to which file I need to change and what variables I need to add, so instead of guessing, I am asking if anyone has done this before and can provide some guidance. I've googled a few times and did not find any real help outside of someone pushing the svn-slack-notifier which is not on the slack integration search.

Windows Server 2012 is what hosts SVN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [SVNSlackNotifier open-source utility](https://github.com/robertmiles3/svn-slack-notifier) for posting commit notifications to Slack. It is listed on the [Community-built Integrations](https://api.slack.com/community#csharp) page and should be much easier to setup than the generic perl script from http://slack.com/apps/A0F827LTA-subversion.

Comment: This actually worked very well. The VisualSVN team reached out and suggested this themselves!