# IntelliJ and SVN - information about update repository

Tags: intellij-idea, svn

I work in one branch at SVN with several people. Is it possible for the IDE to poll from time to time or have changes appear on the remote repository and inform about it (but do not download these changes)?
I use IntelliJ Ultimate as the IDE

Comment: Why do you need this feature to be in the IDE? There are plenty of other common solutions such as email or Slack notifications. You could even add Facebook or Twitter-based notifications.

Comment: The main manager uses Netbeans and he says that information about changes appears on the remote repository. So as free Netbeans has such functionality, he claims that the paid IntelliJ must also have it and you do not need to communicate.I have not used SVN so far, so I do not know if there is such functionality in IntelliJ or not

Answer (score 0):

1. You can configure [email](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00018/) or [Slack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43385412/761095) commit notifications.
2. You can use the [CommitMonitor](https://tools.stefankueng.com/CommitMonitor.html) tool.

Answer (score 0):

There is the Incoming tab in the Version Control toolwindow, that shows commits on the remote. IDE checks for incoming commits once in several minutes. The interval depends on the `Refresh changes every X minutes` setting.

To get to the settings, click the Refresh icon in the tab's toolbar. In older versions, it is available in Settings | Version Control | Background -> VCS History Cache settings

Also, when you edit a file that has a newer version on the server, a warning should appear in a stripe.